# Spark - What is a worker ? (in depth)

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

Alright, I've been working on Spark for 2 months, and I want to understand more deeply the concept of worker in Spark. 
I know that it is called a "node", and it manages his own executors. In my case each worker has 6 executors because I have 6 cores and I configured it that way. 1 executor = 1 JVM, but what is exactly a worker ? And what are all its duties ?

I thank spark's experts in advance to share their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A worker is a machine in your cluster. The master manages all the workers, tells them what to do. The worker has (part of) your data in it's memory which is shared between the executors on the same worker. When workers have to exchange data this is called a shuffle. Let's say each of your 5 machines has 6 cores, then you can have 24 executors while you have 4 workers and one master.